# copy csv file to new file in lua

Tags: file, lua, copy

Can you copy a file in lua? Is this possible? 
You would probably think just insert "devices" into new file however, that creates a new string in each loop -a loop that I did not include in this snippet.

```
file = io.open("temp.csv", "a")
file:write(devices)

file = io.open("log.csv", "w")
file:write("")   

if (count = 15) then

     --copy "temp.csv" to "log.csv"

end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

If the file is small enough, you can read the whole thing into a string, and write the string to the other file:

```
infile = io.open("temp.csv", "r")
instr = infile:read("*a")
infile:close()

outfile = io.open("log.csv", "w")
outfile:write(instr)
outfile:close()
```

You can also invoke your shell to do the copy, though that is platform specific:

```
os.execute("cp temp.csv log.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

Most Lua'ish way to do it, but perhaps not most effective:

```
-- load the ltn12 module
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")

-- copy a file
ltn12.pump.all(
  ltn12.source.file(assert(io.open("temp.csv", "rb"))),
  ltn12.sink.file(assert(io.open("log.csv", "wb")))
)
```

Also before that you need to make sure you have LuaSocket, for a simple environment:

```
sudo luarocks install luasocket
```

Also even better way:

==== util.lua ====

```
-- aliases for protected environments
local assert, io_open
    = assert, io.open

-- load the ltn12 module
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")

-- No more global accesses after this point
if _VERSION == "Lua 5.2" then _ENV = nil end

-- copy a file
local copy_file = function(path_src, path_dst)
  ltn12.pump.all(
      ltn12.source.file(assert(io_open(path_src, "rb"))),
      ltn12.sink.file(assert(io_open(path_dst, "wb")))
    )
end

return {
   copy_file = copy_file;
}
```

===== main.lua ====

```
local copy_file = require("util").copy_file

copy_file("temp.csv", "log.csv")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the open files be closed somewhere?

Comment: I answer myself: `ltn12.source.file` and `sink.file` close the files automatically "when done".